# Storing lambdas generically in a constexpr struct

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a `constexpr` map that relates some scalar key to a `constexpr` structure value, e.g.

```cpp
struct Foo {
    constexpr Foo(int a_, char const *b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {}

    int a;
    char const *b;
};

constexpr const auto map = createMap<int, Foo>({
    {1, Foo{1234, "first"}},
    {2, Foo{5678, "second"}},
});
```

I would like to add an anonymous function to this structure, e.g.

```cpp
template<typename FuncTy>
struct Foo {
    constexpr Foo(int a_, char const *b_, FuncTy c_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) {}

    int a;
    char const *b;
    FuncTy c;
};

constexpr const auto map = createMap<int, Foo>({
    {1, Foo{1234, "first", []() {
        return -1;
    }}},
    {2, Foo{5678, "second", []() {
        return -2;
    }}},
});
```

These lambdas aren't `constexpr` themselves, but let's assume that they all have the same signature and don't capture anything. Unfortunately, this doesn't work as-is because `FuncTy` cannot be deduced. `std::function` is not `constexpr` so it cannot be used. Similarly, defining `FuncTy` as the type of another lambda via `decltype` does not work.

How can I define custom functions for each entry in this map while still keeping it `constexpr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your second example, `Foo` is not a class; it is a template. Templates *generate* things like classes, functions, etc, but the template itself is not what it generates. So unless this `createMap` function takes a template rather than a specific type, `createMap<int, Foo>` is nonsense for your second case.

If you're creating a homogenous container, then each value your container stores must be the same type. So the only way for this to work is for you to enforce a specific type, either one which erases the type of the given lambda or one which enforces a specific function signature. For example, by taking a function pointer:

```
using FuncTySignature = int(); //Insert signature here.
using FuncTyPtr = FuncTySignature*;

struct Foo {
    constexpr Foo(int a_, char const *b_, FuncTyPtr c_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) {}

    int a;
    char const *b;
    FuncTyPtr c;
};
```

Now, `Foo` is no longer a template; it takes a pointer to a function with a specific signature.

If you must fill in these functions with lambdas, then make them non-capturing lambdas, use the exact signature specified by `FuncTySignature`, and convert the lambda to a function pointer when you're applying it. Like this:

```
constexpr const auto map = createMap<int, Foo>({
    {1, Foo{1234, "first", +[]() -> int {
        return -1;
    }}},
    {2, Foo{5678, "second", +[]() -> int {
        return -2;
    }}},
});
```

The `-> int` is just there to make sure that the signature matches. The `+` in front of the lambda is used to provoke a conversion from a lambda functor into a pointer to the lambda function.